Saves from today are gone?
I'm very new to Blender so please bear with me. Recently I closed out a file I was working on and I was making sure to save often (specifically Ctrl+S) before I did so. However, when  I tried to open it a few hours later I found that the program was essentially acting as if I hadn't opened it since yesterday. There's only one autosave on file (from today) and it was essentially from when I first re-opened it for the first time today so all the progress is basically gone. I know that the data is still present somewhere because I can see the most up-to-date version in the preview display, even though it still says yesterday in the Modified section.
Frankly, I'm at a loss for how to recover it; I've tried looking for auto-saves and "blendx" files but no luck. Does anybody know what the issue could be or how I can fix this?


Can you be more specific about what is missing or unchanged in your file that you think should be there? I ask because this question had someone thinking they'd lost all their work, but on multiple levels didn't know what they should be looking for.

The default setup for auto-saving is just ONE version behind the current. Are these the settings you have in Edit > Preferences…? Do you only have a single myfilename.blend1 next to the file you were saving?

You can open that .blend1 by clicking on the filter icon in the Open dialog and enabling the option Backup .blend files; it should nominally be slightly behind your main file.

Other than that, there is not (to my knowledge) a secret directory where many autosaves over time are kept~.
Edit: As mentioned by @JohnEason in the comments below, choosing File ▸ Recover ▸ Auto Save… will open a directory where saved versions of your projects are kept. Perhaps one of these has the content you wanted?
(One other option: are you perhaps on macOS with Time Machine enabled, saving hourly copies?)

You can also use the filter dropdown (funnel icon) in the file selector header bar to select what type of files to show. That allows you to see .blend1 backup files with the main .blend ones and select and load them just as if they were .blend ones.

You can also try File > Recover > Autosave which opens the Temp folder where autosaves go.

@JohnEason Nice, I never knew about either of those!

Also note if you're on Linux the default Temp folder gets wiped on computer restart. Please correct me if I'm wrong, Windows user here.

Under Windows you can also drag and drop a .blend or .blend1 file from the Windows file selector onto an open instance of Blender and you'll get a popup menu asking whether you want to Load, Append or Link it.
